# Titanium: Is there any way at all of displaying text and images together inline without using a webview?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I have a block of text and images together as such:

```
Lorem ipsum etc etc [AN IMAGE HERE] Lorem ipsum etc etc
```

Now I want to display this in my app in the same way (images inline with text).  It seems the only way to do that is with a webview, but my app has about 20 such text areas and putting 20 webviews seems rediculous just for a text/image combo.

Is this simple task do-able in any way outside of a webview??

thanks!

**edit sorry, im new and SO wont let me post an actual image to demonstrate, but you get the idea I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you **need** to use two labels ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2 labels and an imageView in the middle.